# How to store images with Meteor on Herokuapp

Tags: image, meteor, heroku

**Problem:** Store Images location using FilesCollection (ostrio:files)

**Setup:**

```
import { FilesCollection } from 'meteor/ostrio:files';
Images = new FilesCollection({
    collectionName  : 'Images',
    storagePath     : "./Photos",
    downloadRoute   : "/Photos",
    allowClientCode : true, // Required to let you remove uploaded file
    debug           : false,
    public          : true
});
```

**Note:** I tried setting the store path to: `process.env.PWD + '/Photos'` and `"/public/Images"`, and everywhere else i could think of!

**Target Location:** I want to save files to `"/public/Photos/"`

**Note 2:** I noticed that all the images links become broken after each new deployment, that is, if I uploaded an image then the link becomes life until the next deployment.

**PS:** I'm using Meteor 1.5, [Horse-Buildpack](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse), [mlab DB](https://mlab.com/)

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and had to give up. I start using [meteor slingshot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot) which works like a charm. It uploads the images directly to a S3 bucket, and store the URL in the mongo db, so it's imune to deployments.

Comment: Thogh it seems like a very long road to setup slingshot with autoform, without any issues. But unless someone gives me another solution, i'll have to go with it.